# How to detect whether pri resource is avilable in the Application

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, resource-loading

I have included PRI resource in UWP application and im loading with ResourceLoader as like below code

```
ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("ResourceName");
```

How to detect whether i'm having the file in the application. While using the above code, app is taking more time to process this code if the file is not available. If the file is available then app is loaded immediatly

Thanks

Comment: You could simply check if `File.Exists(YourResourcePath)`. Maybe you could also add an extension method to ResourceLoader (untested) `public static bool Exists(this ResourceLoader) { return File.Exists(YourResourcePath); }`. Could make your code more readable `if (ResourceLoader.Exists()) { // DoSomething }`

Comment: When would the file not exist?